# Why can't I use the infinite geometric series formula for this question?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, geometric-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{12}{(-5)^n}$$

If I rewrite this as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 12(-\frac{1}{5})^n$ and then use the infinite geometric series formula, $\frac{a}{1-r}$ where $a = 12$ and $r = (-\frac{1}{5})$? I get 10 but since it starts at 0, I subtracted one from my total equation to get 9, when my textbook says the answer is -2. There must be something I'm doing wrong or misunderstanding.

Comment: In the formula, $a$ is the first value in the series.

Comment: Ahh I see, so I should've subtracted 12 from what I had since 12 was the first element in the series if the series started at $n = 0$. I didn't really think that through. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $|r|<1$, we have
$$
a+ar+ar^2+\ldots=\frac{a}{1-r}.
$$
In your case, $a=-12/5$, $r=-1/5$, giving
$$
\frac{-12/5}{1-(-1/5)}=-2.
$$

---

For fun:  if $S_n=a+ar+ar^2+\ldots+ar^n$ then
$$
rS_n=ar+ar^2+\ldots+ar^{n+1}=S_n-a+ar^{n+1}
$$
so that
$$
S_n=\frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}
$$
and if $|r|<1$ we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}=\frac{a}{1-r}
$$
because
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}r^{n+1}=0.
$$

Comment: Damn, I'm an idiot, I misunderstood the $a$ portion of the formula. Thanks man.

Comment: I'll accept this once it lets me.